# Typescript infer generic type without using the generic type

Tags: typescript

Consider the following code:

```
interface IQuery<TReturn = any> {}
export type ExtractGeneric<T> = T extends IQuery<infer R> ? R : never;
class MyQuery implements IQuery<string> {}
type extractedGenericType = ExtractGeneric<MyQuery>;
```

Why is the compiler not smart enough to know that `extractedGenericType` is not of type `string`? As soon as I use `TReturn` in `IQuery` the compiler can infer the type:

```
interface IQuery<TReturn = any> {
    _type: TReturn;
}
export type ExtractGeneric<T> = T extends IQuery<infer R> ? R : never;
class MyQuery implements IQuery<string> {
    _type: string = "";
}
type extractedType = ExtractGeneric<MyQuery>;
```

Unfortunately in my case it's not an option to actually use the type somewhere in my interface. Any workarounds?

[link to typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.1.0-dev.20201007&ssl=8&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=4#code/PTAEEsDsBcFMCcBmBDAxrUBJAigVwQJ4A8AKgEqzS7ySgC8oykBAfKAN4C+AsAFB8hQsAB4AHAPbxooaAVEYAosOjw00AOKxICcKlJsGJIcq0ATAM5Y8hIlEQJQZNgH5HoAFyhtANwQBuPgEwVAAbZHNLAFkCa3gCCABbURDYBK1oSxx8OKJzFSgAczYuQN5BWXlQYXpQJRU1TW14XSJo2NYA-i7BACNYEPEAd1BByQBrcz4oOCQ0DCybckpqWgYmVg4+UG3QAH0K2E8lqhpOni6RCSkZOUVlVVQNLR09EgNQIxE4SAsrbOI7A4nKBXGQPF5YL54J0+KFwlEYv9EslUulMu1cvlIEVNrwdnsDp48s1sTUAERks6lA5VGp1B5PJotNr-Fh+IA)

Comment: Indeed, it appears that unless the generic variable is bound to some sort of declaration, then it effectively disappears from the type system.