# Why does TypeScript allow to assign between a custom generic type with different parameter types?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I defined a simple custom generic type like this:

```
type MyType<T> = {}
```

Then I use it like this:

```
const a: MyType<string> = {}
const b: MyType<number> = a; // no compilation errors, why?
```

I expect there is a compilation error to stop assigning `a` to `b`, since they seems like have different types, but there is not.

Then I changed the type a little bit by adding an optional field:

```
type MyType<T> = {
  anything?: T
}
```

I didn't change any other code, but now this line:

```
const b: MyType<number> = a;
```

reports a compilation error:

```
TS2322: Type 'MyType2<string>' is not assignable to type 'MyType2<number>'.
   Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.
```

I am not sure why it is. Is there a document to explain this behavior in TypeScript?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64244780/typescript-infer-generic-type-without-using-the-generic-type#comment113611147_64244780) seems very much related...

Comment: structural subtyping. See https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html

Comment: @PeterMortensen Thanks for fixing my gramma errors! I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 3):

TypeScript works on structural subtyping, not nominal subtyping like you may be used to in other languages. This means that we don't care about the names (nominal) of the types - just their internal structure being compatible.

An example would be as follows:

```js
interface Named {
  name: string;
}

class Person {
  name: string;
}

let p: Named;
// OK, because of structural typing
p = new Person();
```

Here we have the same properties (name: string) in both objects, so TypeScript allows assignment between the two.

For your first example, it's actually the same idea. You've created a type `type MyType<T> = {}`

You then create `const a: MyType<string>` and `const b: MyType<number> = a;`.

What is the structure of a? An object with no properties.

What is the structure of b? An object with no properties.

Therefore these objects are equivalent to TypeScript.

In your second example, you now have an actual property that will be different between the two types. Therefore TypeScript views them as not equivalent.

See the handbook for more detail:
*[Type Compatibility](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html)*

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the type parameter `T` anywhere, so it is completely irrelevant what it is.

Remember, the reason why we use typing is because we want to prevent "bad stuff" from happening. That's what rules about type-safety, type-compatibility, assignability, etc. are concerned with.

In your second example, it would be possible for "bad stuff" to happen if we said "yep, those two types are assignment-compatible": code that expects `b.anything` to be a `number` could explode because it gets a `string` instead. And vice versa, code that expects `a.anything` to be a `string` can get tripped up because `b.anything = 42;` is legal.

In the first example, nothing can go wrong: the type makes zero guarantees anyway, so anybody who wants to use `b` *has to* expect weird things to happen regardless.

Comment: Do you mean in the 2nd example, we can write `const a: MyType<any>={anything: 1}` and `const b: MyType<string> = a`, which is bad but has no compilation error? How can I avoid this happen if we could modify the definition code?